# Is it valid to have a <section> tag inside another <section> tag?

Tags: html

Are `<section>` tags allowed to be included within another `<section>` tag? Will it validate in HTML5?

Comment: Ask http://validator.w3.org

Comment: I don't understand the explanations given here but validator.w3.org validates nested sections

Answer (score 206, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#headings-and-sections)! w3 encourages you to *explicitly wrap sections in elements of sectioning content, instead of relying on the implicit sections generated by having multiple headings in one element of sectioning content* and nested <section>'s are allowed.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, since a website is generally divided into one or more sections, use it as long as you feel it describes the structure. A layout can have 1 or even tens of SECTION elements, just know that it is NOT a DIV replacement :)
DIVs are still used and recommended (usually for grouping means).

Comment: This seems to address *sibling* sections. I don't see how it answers the question about *nested* sections.

Comment: can you elaborate on your statement that it is not a `div` replacement? "`divs` are still used and recommended (usually for **[groupings OF WHAT?]**)"

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that will work fine.  At least, it works for me.

You can try it out [here](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_section_tag.cfm).