# section within an another section

Tags: html

Is it semantically wrong to put a `section` or several of them in another `section`?
E.g.:

```
<section>
    ...
    <section>
        ...
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you! autohelp didnt help me without mentioning a word `nested`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they can be included in another `<section>` tag. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916354/is-it-valid-to-have-a-section-tag-inside-another-section-tag) is another answer to this question 
Also checkout [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#headings-and-sections) for more information.

Comment: Yes you are right. Take a look at [this](http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/) maybe that can better answer your question.